# How do I get these numbers to group together?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have

```
for i in range (1,26,1):
    for e in range (1,7,1):
        print i**e
```

I am supposed to get the outcome:

```
1 1 1 1 1  
2 4 8 16 32  
3 9 27 81 243  
…  
25 625 15625 390625 9765625
```

by nesting a for statement within a for statement, but when I run this code every number ends up on its own line.  How do I get it to format like the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.stdout.write`.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Hello World!")
sys.stdout.write("Jane Doe")
```

should print

```
Hello World!JaneDoe
```

Don't forget to print out the line breaks!  Line breaks are coded with `\n`

```
>> sys.stdout.write("Hello World!\n")
Hello World!
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 Solution:

```
for i in range (1,26,1):
    for e in range (1,7,1):
        print( i**e, end=" " )
    print( "" )
```

Python 2 Solution:

```
for i in range(1,26,1):
    row = ""                   
    for e in range(1,7,1):
        row += str(i**e) + " "
    print(row)
```

Comment: This solution only works in python 3, it does not work in python 2.7 unless you import from \_\_future__.  In general, you do not want to import from \_\_future__.  The OP put a python 2.7 tag in the question.